# A NON-NUMERIC VALUE ENCOUNTERED IN WP-INCLUDES/POMO/PLURAL-FORMS.PHP ON LINE 275

Tags: wordpress

На сайте, CMS Wordpress 5.5.1 в комментариях выходит ошибка WARNING: A NON-NUMERIC VALUE ENCOUNTERED IN /WP-INCLUDES/POMO/PLURAL-FORMS.PHP ON LINE 275. Но только при использовании темы [dw-minion](https://www.designwall.com/wordpress/themes/dw-minion/) В других темах все хорошо работает.

```
public function execute( $n ) {
    $stack = array();
    $i     = 0;
    $total = count( $this->tokens );
    while ( $i < $total ) {
        $next = $this->tokens[ $i ];
        $i++;
        if ( 'var' === $next[0] ) {
            $stack[] = $n;
            continue;
        } elseif ( 'value' === $next[0] ) {
            $stack[] = $next[1];
            continue;
        }

        // Only operators left.
        switch ( $next[1] ) {
            case '%':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 % $v2; //ТУТ ОШИБКА!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                break;

            case '||':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 || $v2;
                break;

            case '&&':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 && $v2;
                break;

            case '<':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 < $v2;
                break;

            case '<=':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 <= $v2;
                break;

            case '>':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 > $v2;
                break;

            case '>=':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 >= $v2;
                break;

            case '!=':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 != $v2;
                break;

            case '==':
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 == $v2;
                break;

            case '?:':
                $v3      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v2      = array_pop( $stack );
                $v1      = array_pop( $stack );
                $stack[] = $v1 ? $v2 : $v3;
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Unknown operator "%s"', $next[1] ) );
        }
    }

    if ( count( $stack ) !== 1 ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Too many values remaining on the stack' );
    }

    return (int) $stack[0];
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить этот вопрос

Answer (score 0):

wp-includes/pomo/plural-forms.php отвечает за вывод множественного числа для соответствующей формы слова

проблема в том, что не настроена множественная форма в .pot файле шаблона

Открываем .pot файл шаблона в Poedit, переходим в Каталог > Свойства и указываем следующее выражение для множественного числа:

```
nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11) ? 0 : ((n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20)) ? 1 : 2);
```

Это выражение позволяет использовать три формы множественного числа (русский язык).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]